# Is jqueryui css necessary for using autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I'm using bootstrap for most of my css, and the only reason my using jqueryui is because I am using autocomplete.

Is the jqueryui css absolutely necessary ? Anyway to use only the functional parts ?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead?

Comment: no. I wanted to use more widely used tools.

Comment: You can customize jQueryUI using their download page (http://www.jqueryui.com/download) and get only the pieces that you need. That'll also include only the necessary CSS.

Comment: Did you try to _not_ load the CSS and test the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JQueryUI's download page, if you toggle all options off and check autocomplete checkbox only, even if you select 'no theme' option, your customized .zip package still have .css files so i'm assuming that you need them.

Mentioned page [here.](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.2&themeParams=none&components=1101000000100010000000000000000000000)